# Python - Capture txt files from sub directories with out manually writing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of text file within sub directories called `dir3`. I want to capture its path without manually changing the sub directories names to 1, 2, 3 and run the file again each time (like below). I tried putting `/**` (from other stackoverflow posts) and it is still not picking up the sub directory and its .txt files inside automatically.`dir3` is the only one that has about 10 directories inside like sub_dir_1,sub_dir_2, ... sub_dir_10 with .txt files. How do I get this?

```
directory = r'../dir1/dir2/dir3/sub_dir_1'

# directory = r'../dir1/dir2/dir3/sub_dir_2'
# ...
# directory = r'../dir1/dir2/dir3/sub_dir_10'

for file_name in glob.glob(directory + "/*",recursive=True): # Tried **, / , // ..etc
    with open(file_name, 'r',encoding='utf-8') as file:
        print(directory)
        print(file_name)
```

Basically want to pass in the path: `directory = r'../dir1/dir2/dir3'` and it picks up the subdirectory, its path, and the file name.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Take a look at `os.walk`  https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html

Comment: `glob.glob('**/*.txt', recursive=True)` should work.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me, can't  you pass the path as it is? What errors do you get?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh. Thanks! this is working now.